# How can I add additional elemens to nodes in lists which need to be interesected

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I have two lists of elements which I use to query a third type of elements (in eXist DB). But since I only want those results that are found by both queries (i.e. satisfy two sets of initial parameters) I do an intersection of those two sub-results:

```
let $aList1 := for $elementB in $elementListB return //ElementA[ft:query(@referenceB, $elementB/@id)]
let $aList2 := for $elementC in $elementListC return //ElementA[ft:query(@referenceC, $elementC/@id)]
let $results := $aList1 intersect $aList2
```

The thing is, there is a function i need to call on each element in the starting lists to get some additional info. Normally I would do something like this:

```
let $aList1 := for $elementB in $elementListB
    let $additionalInfo := additionalInfoFunction($elementB)
    return
        <wrapper>
        <additionalInfo>{$additionalInfo}</additionalInfo>
        {
             //ElementA[ft:query(@referenceB, $elementB/@id)]
        }
        </wrapper>
```

However, if I do this I will not be able to perform intersection of `$aList1` and `$aList2` since intersection works with references not values.

I thought of calling the `additionalInfoFunction` after the intersection like this:

```
return for $result in $results
let $elementB := $elementListB[@id = $result/@referenceB]
let $additionalInfo := additionalInfoFunction($elementB)
return
    <wrapper>
    <additionalInfo>{$additionalInfo}</additionalInfo>
    {
         BLA BLA
    }
    </wrapper>
```

But the problem here is that while `$elementListB` and `$elementListC` only contain a few elements, `$results` can contain hundreds which is a problem since `additionalInfoFunction` is relatively expensive.

Is there some clever workaround here which I just can't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XQuery is a functional language with immutable variables and thus without side-effects.

> However, if I do this I will not be able to perform intersection of
>   `$aList1` and `$aList2` since intersection works with references not
>   values.

Whether a function or operator like `intersects` will return references or not is only relevant for the implementation (references could be faster), but as all values are immutable, this can never be a problem to you.

---

The actual problem is related, but not similar; `intersects` does not do a deep-equal but only looks at some internal "node id" (or reference if you want). Creating two elements - though containing the same contents - will creating different nodes, so `intersect` will return no results.

You will have to build your own intersects, which isn't too difficult:

```
let $a := (<a><a1/><a2/></a>, <b><b1/><b2/></b>),
    $b := (<a><a1/><a2/></a>, <c><c1/><c2/></c>)

return $a[
  some $e in $b
  satisfies deep-equal(., $e)
]
```

This will return all elements from `$a` for which there is some element in `$b` which deep-equals the one from `$a`.

Comment: The problem you describe is what I meant. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Anyway, your solution worked, so thank you. Any idea on the performance hit of this approach compared to regular intersection?

Comment: Definitely worse, as `deep-equal` is much more complex as simply comparing references. Also doing the loop in interpreted XQuery will probably be slower than the one for `intersects` written in the implementation's native language. I currently haven't got any eXist instance running; if you do some benchmarking, share them - I'd be interested, too. ;)

Comment: Actually, all my elements had unique id's so I could just compare them in stead of doing a deep equal: `return $a[some $e in $b satisfies $e/@id = ./@id]`

Comment: This will probably even faster: `return $a[@id = ($b/@id)`. `=` compares on a kind of set semantic, so if (one element in) `$a` equals one element in `$b`, it will return true. Actually does the same, but compiles directly to native code.

Comment: Thanks Ranon, I will try this today as performance might be an issue with many elements. Is there a similar way to make something equivalent of a union. With the other approach I was doing `($a, $b[every $e in $a satisfies $e/@id != ./@id])`

Comment: Short on time, thus no code, but just think on the semantics of the union: Take all from `$a` and all from `$b` not contained in `$a`. There is a keyword `union`, but again you can't use it on element nodes.